# Property annotation that checks assignment to a guard value initially set to None

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a property that only gets computed once per instance and that uses `None` as a guard value.  This is a pretty common pattern with properties.

What's the best way to annotate it?

### edit/clarification:

This question is about how to use mypy to validate my property's code.  Not about how to refactor the code.  The property's type is just the way I want it, as a non-Optional int.  Assume, for example, that the downstream code will do `print(book.the_answer+1)`.

The, incorrect, assignment of a string and a None are fully intentional to break the contract defined by the property's expectations and I wanted mypy to flag them.

#### Try #1

```
class Book:

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    _the_answer = None #line 6
    # _the_answer : int = None #line 7

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s => %s" % (self.title, self.the_answer)

    @property
    def the_answer(self)->int:
        """always should be an int.  Not an Optional int"""
        if self._the_answer is None:
            if "Guide" in self.title:
                #this is OK
                self._the_answer = 42
            elif "Woolf" in self.title:
                #this is wrong, mypy should flag it.
                self._the_answer = "?, I haven't read it"  # line 21
            else:
                #mypy should also flag this
                self._the_answer = None #line 24

        return self._the_answer #line 26

print(Book("Hitchhiker's Guide"))
print(Book("Who's afraid of Virginia Woolf?"))
print(Book("War and Peace"))
```

Output:

```
Hitchhiker's Guide => 42
Who's afraid of Virginia Woolf? => ?, I haven't read it
War and Peace => None
```

Mypy's output:

```
test_prop2.py:21: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "Optional[int]")
test_prop2.py:26: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[int]", expected "int")
```

There's really nothing necessarily wrong with line 26, it all depends on what got assigned in the IFs.  21 and 24 are both incorrect, but mypy only catches 21.

Note: that if I change the property return to `return cast(int, self._the_answer) #line 26` then it leaves that alone at least.

If I add typing to the guard value, `_the_answer`:

#### Try #2, type the guard value as well:

```
class Book:

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    #_the_answer = None
    _the_answer : int = None #line 7

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s => %s" % (self.title, self.the_answer)

    @property
    def the_answer(self)->int:
        """always should be an int.  Not an Optional int"""
        if self._the_answer is None:
            if "Guide" in self.title:
                #this is OK
                self._the_answer = 42
            elif "Woolf" in self.title:
                #this is wrong.  mypy flags it.
                self._the_answer = "?, I haven't read it"  # line 21
            else:
                #mypy should also flag this
                self._the_answer = None #line 24

        return self._the_answer #line 26

print(Book("Hitchhiker's Guide"))
print(Book("Who's afraid of Virginia Woolf?"))
print(Book("War and Peace"))
```

Same running output, but mypy has different errors:

```
test_prop2.py:7: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "int")
```

and it doesn't type check lines 21, 24 and 26 (actually it did once but then I changed the code and it hasnt since).

And if I change line #7 to `_the_answer : int = cast(int, None)`, then mypy is entirely silent and warns me about nothing.

#### Versions:

```
mypy   0.720
Python 3.6.8
```

Comment: `from typing import Union`, and annotate it with `Union[int, str, None]`

Comment: but str is wrong and I need it caught. so is None - that’s the nature of a property guard value.  anyway, which lines are you proposing to annotate?

Comment: `_the_answer : Optional[int] = None #line 7` can work with str but not None and also requires you to change the return type to `Optional[int]`. I think the only best way should be using something like `-1` as guard value...

Comment: Why use `_the_answer = 42` instead of `_the_answer = "42"`? There is a difference between a number and a string that happens to be the representation of a number.

Comment: @chepner  very much on purpose.  I wanted to see how I could leverage mypy to analyze typed properties.  The int is on purpose.  The wrongful assignment of a string as well - the whole point is to see how mypy can be used to catch it.  In the meantime I have found something that seems to work and will post it when I am on my laptop - I’ve removed typing from the guard var, but added an extra int-typed var right above the if statement.  Thats the variable used to assign values and both None and string assignments get flagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a night's sleep I got the solution: splitting up the *typing* responsibilities from the *guarding* responsibilities.

- the guard variable, `self/cls._the_answer` is left untyped.
- In line 15, right under the guard condition which tells me the instance hasn't had that property computed yet, I type-hint a new variable name, `answer`.

Both incorrect assignments, in 21 and 24 are now flagged.

```
from typing import cast
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    _the_answer = None

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s => %s" % (self.title, self.the_answer)

    @property
    def the_answer(self)->int:
        """always should be an int.  Not an Optional int"""
        if self._the_answer is None:
            answer : int  #line 15:    this is where the typing happens
            if "Guide" in self.title:
                #this is OK  ✅
                answer = 42
            elif "Woolf" in self.title:
                #this is wrong  ❌
                answer = "?, I haven't read it"  # line 21
            else:
                #mypy should also flag this  ❌
                answer = None #line 24
            self._the_answer = answer
        return cast(int, self._the_answer) #line 26

print(Book("Hitchhiker's Guide"))
print(Book("Who's afraid of Virginia Woolf?"))
print(Book("War and Peace"))
```

Same actual run output as before.

#### mypy output:

Now, both problem lines are flagged ;-)

```
test_prop4.py:21: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "int")
test_prop4.py:24: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "int")
```

What about the `cast` in line 26?  What if nothing assigns `answer` in the if statements? Without the `cast`, I'd probably be getting a warning. Could I have assigned a default value as in `answer : int = 0` in line 15?

I could, but unless there really is a good application-level default, I'd rather have things blow up right away at execution (`UnboundLocalError` on answer) rather than making mypy happy but having to chase down some weird runtime value.

That last bit is totally dependent on what your application is expecting, a default value may be the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

While mypy may not be flagging the exact lines you want to have flagged, it *is* legitimately reporting that your `the_answer` implementation is unsound and is not guaranteed to return an int.

Both of your two errors:

```
test_prop2.py:21: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "Optional[int]")
test_prop2.py:26: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[int]", expected "int")
```

...are actually correct. Mypy inferred that your `_the_answer` field has a type of `Optional[int]` because the very first time you try assigning a non-None value to that field, you assign an int. (The first branch of your if statement).

The second error is also correct: since you assign `None` to `self._the_answer` on line 24, the return value is clearly going to be `None` in some cases. So, mypy reports you have an error when you actually try *returning* your field.

It would be incorrect for mypy to actually report an error on line 24. Since `_the_answer` is inferred to be type `Optional[int]`, there's really nothing inherently wrong with assigning a `None` value to that field. So instead, mypy defers the error until it knows for certain that there's something wrong.

Note that if you actually fix your code, mypy will stop reporting any errors. For example, the following program type-checks cleanly:

```py
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    _the_answer = None

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s => %s" % (self.title, self.the_answer)

    @property
    def the_answer(self) -> int:
        if self._the_answer is None:
            if "Guide" in self.title:
                self._the_answer = 42
            else:
                self._the_answer = 100

        return self._the_answer
```

Here, mypy is capable of deducing that `self._the_answer` will always be an int in all cases by the time we hit the return, so realizes that the type of `_the_answer` can temporarily be narrowed to `int` within just that function.

Mypy's type inference algorithm isn't perfect, of course. If your actual code is more complicated then this and mypy doesn't seem to infer the right thing, you can help it along by adding in a few `assert isinstance(self._the_answer, int)` to force mypy to narrow the type.

You can check what mypy thinks the type of your field is at any point by sprinkling in a few `reveal_type(self._the_answer)` -- when mypy encounters that pseudo-function, it'll report what type it thinks that expression is in addition to reporting any type errors.

---

Somewhat unrelated, I'd also recommend you explicitly annotate your `_the_answer` field -- e.g. do `_the_answer: Optional[int] = None` on line seven.

Right now, mypy is inferring that `_the_answer` is `Optional[int]` just by checking the first non-None assignment. But if you were to rearrange your code so that you accidentally have the (incorrect) string assignment come first, mypy would infer the type to be `Optional[str]` instead. This is obviously somewhat fragile.

Answer (score 0):

I would make two changes to your code:

1. Don't predefine `_the_answer` at all; create it on demand when `the_answer` is first accessed.
2. `_the_answer` should *always* be a string; you aren't going to do math or anything else number-like with `42`; it's just a label that happens to *look* like a number. Likewise, no answer is `""`, not `None`. If you need to be more specific about there being no answer, raise an exception instead and let the caller deal with it.

With this in mind, your code becomes

```
class Book:

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s => %s" % (self.title, self.the_answer)

    @property
    def the_answer(self)->str:
        try:
            answer = self._the_answer
        except AttributeError:
            if "Guide" in self.title:
                answer = "42"
            elif "Woolf" in self.title:
                answer = "?, I haven't read it"
            else:
                answer = ""
                # or raise ValueError("%s has no answer" % (self.title,))
            self._the_answer = answer

        return answer
```

Now you aren't in the situation of having to provide a static type annotation for a variable whose type can change at run-time.